# Powerbuilder: Getting faulting module PBDWE110.DLL in application

Tags: powerbuilder

​Hello,

I'm running a legacy application written with Powerbuilder 11.2.

Very intermittently, the application closes on the users with the popup 'has stopped working and needs to close', and event log 1000 is logged:

---

Faulting application: myapp.exe, version: 9.1.0.0, time stamp: 0x47b93d70
Faulting module name: pbdwe110.dll, version: 11.2.0.8407, time stamp: 0x47c769bf Exception code: 0xc0000005

Fault offset: 0x001080fd

Faulting process id: 0x304

Faulting application start time: 0x01d2553e7d206cff

Faulting application path: C:\ProgramFolder\myapp.exe

Faulting module path: C:\ProgramFolder\pbdwe110.dll Report Id: b5535cd1-c133-11e6-82db-acfdce8910e7

Faulting package full name:

Faulting package-relative application ID:

---

This seems to be happening more on Windows 8.1 than it is on Windows 7, but I'm not sure.

Has anyone else had this?  The version of pbdwe110.dll is 11.2.0.8407.  Are there any other versions of pbdwe110.dll I could use?

Comment: That dll is for powerbuilder data window engine, so chances are it is related to a problem with one of your datawindows.  I don't think you can just switch it out for another version, as you would have to update the source for each of your datawindows with the new version number.  I doubt that would be the only change you would have to make either, so I would consider it a non-starter to try and replace it.

Comment: Try the following I found on google: A valid default printer need to be selected to open a composite datawindow